# What is the most upvoted question in Arqade?

Tags: discussion, voting

I want to know what is the most upvoted question in Arqade so I can use it to learn what constitutes a high quality question. Does anyone know what is the most upvoted question on Arqade?

Comment: Note that a lot of upvotes on older questions happened because they had a very weird, almost clickbaity title related to a rare game mechanic and ended up on the Hot Network Questions list, which makes them appear to users all over the network and as such gives them a much greater audience. These days if a question like that ends up on the Hot Network Questions, moderators tend to edit the question so they're not as clickbaity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think asking the best question possible shouldn't be your goal here: you ask questions because you want information.
Apart from that, it is highly capricious. It depends, for example, tremendously on the game you ask after, and whether or not that game is at a peak of popularity. And then there are less significant factors, like length, grammar, clarity, time of day, humor, the amount of online users, the title given, &c.

Nevertheless, [here is the list](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq&tab=votes), and this is the most upvoted question:

[How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)

Be sure to return once you have completed your analysis - it might give us some good old psychological insights into what the average gamer is like :)

Comment: An alternate way to search for most voted questions is to enter the search query in the URL: [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes)